# Deserializing many network messages without using an ad-hoc parser implementation

Tags: haskell, deserialization

I have a question pertaining to deserialization. I can envision a solution using Data.Data, Data.Typeable, or with GHC.Generics, but I'm curious if it can be accomplished without generics, SYB, or meta-programming.

**Problem Description:**

Given a list of [String] that is known to contain the fields of a locally defined algebraic data type, I would like to deserialize the [String] to construct the target data type. I could write a parser to do this, but I'm looking for a generalized solution that will deserialize to an arbitrary number of data types defined within the program without writing a parser for each type. With knowledge of the number and type of value constructors an algebraic type has, it's as simple as performing a **read** on each string to yield the appropriate values necessary to build up the type. However, I don't want to use generics, reflection, SYB, or meta-programming (unless it's otherwise impossible).

Say I have around 50 types defined similar to this (all simple algebraic types composed of basic primitives (no nested or recursive types, just different combinations and orderings of primitives) :

```
data NetworkMsg = NetworkMsg { field1 :: Int, field2 :: Int, field3 :: Double}

data NetworkMsg2 = NetworkMsg2 { field1 :: Double, field2 :: Int, field3 :: Double }
```

I can determine the data-type to be associated with a [String] I've received over the network using a tag id that I parse before each [String].

**Possible conjectured solution path:**

Since data constructors are first-class values in Haskell, and actually have a type-- Can NetworkMsg constructor be thought of as a function, such as:

```
NetworkMsg :: Int -> Int -> Double -> NetworkMsg
```

Could I transform this function into a function on tuples using uncurryN then copy the [String] into a tuple of the same shape the function now takes?

```
NetworkMsg' :: (Int, Int, Double) -> NetworkMsg
```

I don't think this would work because I'd need knowledge of the value constructors and type information, which would require Data.Typeable, reflection, or some other metaprogramming technique.

Basically, I'm looking for automatic deserialization of many types without writing type instance declarations or analyzing the type's shape at run-time. If it's not feasible, I'll do it an alternative way.

Comment: I would consider myself a Haskell novice, so maybe I'm overlooking something obvious.

Comment: I don't quite the get the bit with `Traversable`. `NetworkMsg` can't be that, or `Applicative`, because its kind doesn't match.

Comment: It's also not clear to me what you're asking for here. Do I get it right that you want to parse `[String]` into tuples (or newtypes of tuples), where each `String` in the list encodes a tuple field?

Comment: @AndrásKovács, thanks I revised the question to try to make it more clear. I was proposing the idea of writing an instance of Applicative on each data type because I thought it would allow me to perform a sequence of reads and combine the results into the type, but I was just brainstorming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that the constructors are essentially just functions so you can write generic instances for any number of types by just writing instances for the functions. You'll still need to write a separate instance 
for all the different numbers of arguments, though.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import Text.Read
import Control.Applicative

class FieldParser p r where
    parseFields :: p -> [String] -> Maybe r

instance Read a => FieldParser (a -> r) r where
    parseFields con [a] = con <$> readMaybe a
    parseFields _ _ = Nothing

instance (Read a, Read b) => FieldParser (a -> b -> r) r where
    parseFields con [a, b] = con <$> readMaybe a <*> readMaybe b
    parseFields _ _ = Nothing

instance (Read a, Read b, Read c) => FieldParser (a -> b -> c -> r) r where
    parseFields con [a, b, c] = con <$> readMaybe a <*> readMaybe b <*> readMaybe c
    parseFields _ _ = Nothing

{- etc. for as many arguments as you need -}
```

Now you can use this type class to parse any message based on the constructor as long as the type-checker is able to figure out the resulting message type from context (i.e. it is not able to deduce it simply from the given constructor for these sort of multi-param type class instances).

```
data Test1 = Test1 {fieldA :: Int} deriving Show
data Test2 = Test2 {fieldB ::Int, fieldC :: Float} deriving Show

test :: String -> [String] -> IO ()
test tag fields = case tag of
    "Test1" -> case parseFields Test1 fields of
        Just (a :: Test1) -> putStrLn $ "Succesfully parsed " ++ show a
        Nothing -> putStrLn "Parse error"
    "Test2" -> case parseFields Test2 fields of
        Just (a :: Test2) -> putStrLn $ "Succesfully parsed " ++ show a
        Nothing -> putStrLn "Parse error"
```

I'd like to know how exactly you use the message types in the application, though, because having each message as its separate type makes it very difficult to have any sort of generic message handler.

Is there some reason why you don't simply have a single message data type? Such as

```
data NetworkMsg
    = NetworkMsg1 {fieldA :: Int}
    | NetworkMsg2 {fieldB :: Int, fieldC :: Float}
```

Now, while the instances are built in pretty much the same way, you get much better type inference since the result type is always known.

```
instance Read a => MessageParser (a -> NetworkMsg) where
    parseMsg con [a] = con <$> readMaybe a

instance (Read a, Read b) => MessageParser (a -> b -> NetworkMsg) where
    parseMsg con [a, b] = con <$> readMaybe a <*> readMaybe b

instance (Read a, Read b, Read c) => MessageParser (a -> b -> c -> NetworkMsg) where
    parseMsg con [a, b, c] = con <$> readMaybe a <*> readMaybe b <*> readMaybe c

parseMessage :: String -> [String] -> Maybe NetworkMsg
parseMessage tag fields = case tag of
    "NetworkMsg1" -> parseMsg NetworkMsg1 fields
    "NetworkMsg2" -> parseMsg NetworkMsg2 fields
    _ -> Nothing
```

I'm also not sure why you want to do type-generic programming specifically without actually using any of the tools meant for generics. GHC.Generics, SYB or Template Haskell is usually the best solution for this kind of problem.

Comment: Shang, this is precisely what I was looking for! Thank you. I do have a master message type that represents the algebraic sum type of all of the message type constructors. I wanted to do it this way partly due to curiosity, and partly because I was hoping for something idiomatic and with less library dependencies.